# How to add social media icons to a react component?

Tags: reactjs

I have created **Card component** using **.jsx** file and loaded in a **.js** file. And it is working. Here I want to know, **how to add social media icons** to the card?

This is for a new React project, hope to run mongodb. I have tried using this

```
npm install -g bower
bower install bootstrap-social.
```

But did not work.

```
const Card = props=>{
    return(

      <div className="card text-center shadow">
          <div className="overflow">
              <img src={props.imgsrc} alt='image 1' className="card-img-top" />
          </div>
          <div className="card-body text-dark">
              <h4 className="card-title">{props.title} </h4>
              <p className="card-text text-secondary">
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, 
              </p>
              **<a href="#" className="btn btn-outline-success">Go Anywhere</a>**
          </div>
      </div>  
    );

};
```

I expected to change above "Go Anywhere" button to twitter button. And to put some other buttons like Facebook, Instagram and so on in the same row.

Comment: Use library called `react-icons`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install any icon library having social icons. You need to do:

```
npm install react-feather --save( run from the project folder )
```

```
import { IconName } from 'react-feather';
```

Link for `react-feather`: https://github.com/feathericons/react-feather

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

you can use React Icons
it comprises of a bunch of icons from font-awesome, material design etc

```
npm install react-icons

       OR

yarn add react-icons
```

then import your favourite icons e.g

```
import {FaTwitter} from 'react-icons/fa'
```

you can browse a bunch of several icons at:

```
https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [webpack-webfont](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-webfont) and convert svg custom icons to webfont

you can download icons from [flaticon.com](https://www.flaticon.com/)